# Struts2 action always returning success

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm a beginner in STRUTS2 and I want to test two Actions.

The first Action `Product` work correctly. When I enter "hello" return success otherwise error.

But the second Action `CatererTyp` return always success.

Can somebody please explain me why?

Here is Product.java

```
package com.javatpoint;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Product extends ActionSupport {
private int id;
private String name;
private float price;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String execute() {
    if(name.equals("hallo")){

        return SUCCESS;
    }
    else{
    return ERROR;
    }
}
}
```

CatererType.java

```
package com.javatpoint;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class CatererType extends ActionSupport {

private String description;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String excute() {

    if (description.equals("hello")) {

        return ERROR;
    } else {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
}
```

accessdiened.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head>
<body>
You are not authorized to view this page.
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
The Caterer Type: <s:property value="description"/> was inserted <br/>
```

adminpage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %> 
<html> 
<center>
<s:form action="caterertype">  
<s:textfield name="description" label="Caterer Type"></s:textfield>  
<s:submit value="save"></s:submit>  
</s:form>  
</center>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts  
Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  
<struts>  
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"  />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">  

<action name="product" class="com.javatpoint.Product" method="execute">  
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>  
<result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>
</action>  
<action name="caterertype" class="com.javatpoint.CatererType" method="execute"> 
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result> 
<result name="error">AccessDenied.jsp</result>
</action>

</package>  
</struts>
```

Comment: I note some differences search if this is the problem:                         <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result> with backslash
</action>  
<action name="caterertype" class="com.javatpoint.CatererType" method="execute"> 
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result> 
<result name="error">AccessDenied.jsp</result> without backslash                  and                                                                                                                  in the action one wrote hello other hallo

Comment: i removed the backslash in both and added it in both but still returning always success in CatererType

Comment: excuse me can you write the method excute() in CatererType like in Product

Comment: i did it but excute still always returning success

Comment: I'm not sure but you can trim() the string in input in action class

Comment: im sure the problem is not at the equals string. the problem is that i the action results success and error are duplicated. so i must do something to get the result outcomes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95190/discussion-between-abdelhak-and-user3232446).